# How to get most downloads records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables :

`wallpapers`:

```
id     img        cat_id
```

`downloads` :

```
 id     wall_id
 1       10
 2       10
 3       2
 .       .
```

I would like to get all wallpapers that have most downloads from a specific `cat_id` .

my query :

```
SELECT *
FROM wallpapers
    WHERE cat_id = 10 
    AND id IN 
    (SELECT wall_id
        FROM (SELECT wall_id, count(*) 
                FROM downloads 
                GROUP BY wall_id
                ORDER BY count(*) DESC))
```

but it returns nothing !

---

my framework is `Codeingiter`:

```
    $rows = $this->db->query($sql);

    var_dump($rows);
    return;
```

output :

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: Why not make a join instead of using a subquery?

Comment: Which one of them have more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just group them by wall_id in that way you can get each wall_id total downloads and then
order them by them count

```
ORDER BY count(downloads.wall_id) DESC
```

and add limit

```
LIMIT 3
```

assuming you want to get the top 3 most downloads
so your final query would be like this

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     wallpapers 
JOIN     downloads 
ON       wallpapers.id = downloads.wall_id 
GROUP BY downloads.wall_id ORDER BY count(downloads.wall_id) DESC limit 3
```

Comment: Note that the GROUP BY is invalid and wont work with newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.)